# How to avoid delete confirmation in LibreOffice Calc for OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice

Windows users can avoid the pesky delete confirmation dialog in Calc by using their `Delete` key instead of `Backspace` (according to [the documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Deleting_Contents))

My Macbook only has a `Delete` key and so I can't avoid the dialog from popping up every time I just want to delete some content. I have tried to use `Cut`, but this also removes the formatting.

Is there a key combination available on OSX that deletes a cell's content and leave the formatting in place like the `Delete` key on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fn+Delete` clears the content of a cell without the prompt. It is also the Mac equivalent of the Windows `Delete` key.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser -- thanks for posting!  For more information about the site, the [tour](http://superuser.com/tour) and [help](http://superuser.com/help) pages are a great place to start. Enjoy!